# Persisting Data With Hive Container

Tags: docker, apache-spark, hive, persistence

I'm using a Docker based Spark/Hadoop/Hive environment.

With all the configurations so far, I'm able to persist the HDFS containers data, communicate Spark with all the other containers, create and work with databases and tables on Hive from multiple file formats.

The problem is:
- As soon as I close the interactive Docker terminal for the Hive Server container,
all the databases and tables are gone;
- The parquet files I used to create the Hive tables are still persisted on the HDFS,
but the table itself on Hive is gone;

Am I able to persist the databases and tables? Is there something I'm missing on the docker-compose file or maybe the environment variables? Or did I misunderstood the purpose/function of Hive on my system?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Hive uses an Embedded Derby database. You'll need to setup an external database such as MySQL/MariaDB or Postgres container, then use a Hive Metastore container, and then you can run a HiveServer2 container (or other Hive Client like Spark or Presto) that connects to **the Metastore**.

The database container is where the volume mount should be configured.

I'd also suggest using Ozone or MinIO as HDFS-compatible storage
containers rather than HDFS itself; that way, you don't need a NameNode container, and your files are likely not that large, anyway.